# parallelize bisection

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, binary-search, bisection

Consider the bisection algorithm to find square root. Every step depends on the previous, so in my opinion it's not possibile to parallelize it. Am I wrong?

Consider also similar algorithm like binary search.

**edit**

My problem is not the bisection, but it is very similar. I have a monotonic function `f(mu)` and I need to find the mu where `f(mu)<alpha`. One core need 2 minutes to compute `f(mu)` and I need a very big precision. We have a farm of ~100 cores. My first attemp was to use only 1 core and then scan all value of `f` with a dynamic step, depending on how close I am to `alpha`. Now I want to use the whole farm, but my only idea is to compute 100 value of `f` at equal spaced points.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by *parallelize*, and at what granularity. For example you could use instruction level parallelism (e.g. SIMD) to find square roots for a set of input values.

Binary search is trickier, because the control flow is data-dependent, as is the number of iterations, but you could still conceivably perform a number of binary searches in parallel so long as you allow for the maximum number of iterations (log2 N).

Answer (score 1):

Even if these algorithms could be parallelized (and I'm not sure they can), there is very little point in doing so.

Generally speaking, there is very little point in attempting to parallelize algorithms that already have sub-linear time bounds (that is, T < O(n)).  These algorithms are already so fast that extra hardware will have very little impact.

Furthermore, it is not true (in general) that all algorithms with data dependencies cannot be parallelized.  In some cases, for example, it is possible to set up a pipeline where different functional units operate in parallel and feed data sequentially between them.  Image processing algorithms, in particular, are frequently amenable to such arrangements.

Problems with no such data dependencies (and thus no need to communicate between processors) are referred to as "embarrassingly parallel".  Those problems represent a small subset of the space of all problems that can be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

Many algorithms have several steps that each step **depend** on **previous** step,Some those algorithm can changed steps to doing parallel and some impossible to parallel, I think BinarySearch is of second type, You not wrong, But you can paralleled binary search with **multiple Search**.

Comment: can you explain what is multple search?

Comment: My means is if you have n(>1) key and must search those with BinarySearch, You can doing this n search in parallel.